# remove certain group of character from string

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I want to remove the middle, last name from actors column. The actors column has group of actor together. the name of actor is like firstName[-middleName-lastName]. the characters column can have any no of combination of actor. The name of different actor is separated by +.
suppose data is like:

```
actors
wahab+mira_sah
zayra_khan+daniel_day_lewis+danial_craig
tom_cruise+tom_hanks
```

the expected output be like:

```
actors
wahab+mira
zayra+daniel+danial
tom+tom
```

Answer (score 2):

Versions of MySQL earlier than 8+ can't really handle this type of problem, at least not right out the box (without adding e.g. a UDF).  One very appropriate tool for this problem is regex.  Fortunately, MySQL 8+ *does* support regex replacement:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'actors' AS col UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wahab+mira_sah' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'zayra_khan+daniel_day_lewis+danial_craig' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tom_cruise+tom_hanks'
)

SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '_[^+]+', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: isn't `[^+]+` faster to execute? rather than `[^_+]+` ?

Comment: I think you can just get away with `_[^+]+` for the regex.

Comment: @Nick You're right, since the OP doesn't want anything after the very first underscore.